# ¿Es posible eliminar la información adicional que muestra org.apache.commons.logging.Log?

Tags: java

Me gustaría saber si es posible omitir la información adicional que muestra el Log.

Actualmente obtengo algo parecido a lo siguiente:

```
jul. 07, 2023 12:31:26 P. M. es.Logger logInfo
ADVERTENCIA: miMensaje
```

Quisiera omitir todo y que solo se muestre *miMensaje*

Comment: Agrega el código de lo que has intentado hasta el momento. Te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer [example] y [ask]

Comment: Puedes configurar commons-logging.properties con el mensaje solo, pero ¿Qué caso tendría si desprecias todas las prestaciones del logger? comparado con -por ejemplo- redireccionar la salida de consola a un archivo, o escribir directamente a tu propio archivo.

Answer (score -1):

Es posible que el siguiente articulo te pueda ayudar:
[Propiedades log level](https://www.java67.com/2021/10/how-to-set-logging-level-in-spring-boot-.html)

logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG
logging.level.com.howtodoinjava=DEBUG

#this is used to store the loggers in the tempdir folder
logging.file=${java.io.tmpdir}/application.log

## The way how you create the logging files

logging.pattern.file= %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%

## The way how you write the logging patterns within the file

logging.pattern.console= %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%